# Exclude Statement in SQL

Tags: sql, database

How to exclude data from an SQL database using an SQL statement? My situation is I have a user login to their profile page where they will be able to friend people. I want to display all users except themselves that are found in the SQL database.

Comment: This is a really basic question. Consider a good book on DB theory and SQL, it will greatly benefit you. See my recommendations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046668/database-programming-concepts/1604980#1604980

Answer (score 11):

Maybe just

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    Users
WHERE
    UserId <> @ThisUserId
```

Or using a Difference Union (The [`EXCEPT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx) keyword in SQL Server, not sure about other RDBMS implementations)

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    Users

EXCEPT

SELECT *
FROM 
    Users
WHERE
    UserId = @ThisUserId
```

Comment: The INTERSECT keyword can also be extremely useful too, for finding results common to all resultsets

Answer (score 5):

How about:

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE person_id != $current_user_id
```

Comment: That should probably be person_id <> current_user_id

Comment: Why?  The RDBMS I use supports != operator.

Comment: Interesting, just checked and SQL Server and MySQL support !=

Comment: +1 Hehe alright since I learned something new from your post :)

Comment: `!=` is ANSI standard.  It's been supported in Oracle since 9i; MySQL since at least 4.1

Comment: @OMG Ponies:  No, `<>` is ANSI standard.  `!=` is supported by most RDBMS brands, but it's not specified in ANSI SQL.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/723195/should-i-use-or-for-not-equal-in-tsql/723426#723426

Answer (score 4):

Yes I know Im late with this one.

Anyhow as I stumpled over those comments here while looking for an answer to a question  similare to the one ask here ("how to exlcude data from a query") I was a bit confused.

Confused because I knew the answer I was looking for was not only more simple, but even more elegant then the ones proposed here. I once knew the answer, but forgot it. I came here because I was too lazy to remember...

So I struggled hard to remember the easy solution and then it came back to my mind.

So assume you have the two tables "Email" and "UnwantedEmail" with both carring the one column "Address". The query to only get the wanted email addresses, those addresses which are in "Email" but not in "UnwantedEmail" could look like the following:

```
SELECT Email.Address FROM UnwantedEmail
RIGHT JOIN Email ON UnwantedEmail.Address=Email.Address
WHERE UnwantedEmail.Address Is Null;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from Foo where UserName not in ('Rohan', 'Rohan's friend', .....)
```

Is this useful?

Answer (score 0):

If you know what that user's unique ID is you could use something like this for example:

```
SELECT * FROM usertable WHERE id!='myuserid'
```

What I do with one of my authentication scripts is store the information for the person that is currently logged in in a variable so it would look like this in PHP:

```
SELECT * FROM usertable WHERE id!='check(id)'
```