# How exclude CREATE DATABASE entry from export option of phpMyAdmin of XAMPP

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

I am exporting database from phpMyAdmin of XAMPP, and it includes entry to `CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS` and enter database name there, that creates problem while importing on anywhere else or live server.

How can I exclude that statement?

Comment: Wsalam, similar problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693457/exclude-statement-in-sql). May it helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

What problem or error does it cause? MySQL should create the database if it doesn't exist, and ignore that line if it does, so it seems strange that you would have any trouble with it. Looking in the MySQL manual, it seems this syntax is supported since version 3.23, so if your MySQL is older that that, I could see it causing an error message (in that case, as the most recent release is more than 10 years old, I'd suggest you upgrade :-)

Regardless, you can exclude or modify that statement by selecting the "Custom" radio button when exporting. Scroll down to the "Object creation options" and you should see checkboxes for CREATE TABLE and IF NOT EXISTS, you can deselect the appropriate options for your situation.